Error while creating a post in LinkedIn page using LinkedIn API
I was stuck at this error:
{
    "Service Error Code": 100,
    "message": "Field Value validation failed in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/author]",
    "status": 403
}

I used the post API: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts
and the body mentioned in the documentation accordingly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api?view=li-lms-unversioned&tabs=http
Should I need to allow the Access of Advertising API and Lead Sync API also? and then should I try or else is there any way to post it.
I used the organization ID from the URL when we click on the LinkedIn page.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
